# In bash, when executing a script with an stdin, how to enter values automatically?

Tags: bash

I have a binary which asks a user to enter some values, like this:

```
./binary
Please enter some value:
```

I would like to automatize this task and gives the binary several values in a loop:

```
for i in (1...1000)
do
./binary 
// Some function to give $i as a value
done
```

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's bash, a here string is the way to go.

```
for i in {1..1000}; do
  ./binary <<< "$i"
done
```

When choosing whether to redirect or use a pipe, consider your [amount of data](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219804/resource-usage-using-pipe-and-here-string).

In response to your comment: the best way to handle this would be to modify `./binary` so that error handling is there. I'm assuming you can't, though, given the name, so here's what I'd do.

For a `./binary` with this logic:

```
#!/bin/bash

read var
if (( var == 4 )); then
  echo "OK"
  exit 0
else
  echo "NOT OK"
  exit 1
fi
```

This loop will output only `4`.

```
for i in {1..10}; do
  if [[ $( ./binary <<< $i ) == "OK" ]]; then
    echo $i
  fi
done
```

Ideally you wouldn't capture the output and check it later, but if you're looking for a specific string (rather than an exit code), this is a way to go.

Comment: Ok, and last question: how can I display only occurence with the chosen output of the binary (Let's say I have only one "OK" message from ./binary some_number)

Comment: Since it's a fairly minor modification, I'll edit this answer. In general, though, you should modify your question or ask another.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in {1..1000}
do
    echo $i | ./binary 
done
```

Comment: there is no "$" in the loop expression before the i (I made a mistake in my post, I just edited), but even without the $ I have and error: "bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('"

Comment: There are no parenthesis in my example; I'm using {}. :)